# Problems with {% extends 'base.html' %} command in Django

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I have been bothering so long with this problem. I don't where I have made a mistake. Been sitting over this for 1h.... Someone, please help.

It's home.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}


        
            {% block head %}
            Home
            {% endblock %}
        
            
                {% block body %}
                <h1>HomeHome</h1>
                {% endblock %}
```

---

And it's base.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


    
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
        {% block head %}
        Base
        {% endblock %}
    
    

                {% block body %}
                <h1>BaseBase</h1>
                {% endblock %}
    
    </body>
```

My page shows base.html with no changes - it doesn't use {% extends 'base.html' %}

thank you :)

Comment: are you sure you render home.html? like `return render(request, '....../home.html')`

Comment: Yes. I actually corrected it so: return render(request, 'Folder/home.html') and now it shows pure home.html filme with no adnotations to base.html...

Comment: in your base.html you have only visible elements inside the block tags which are replaced by the home.html block contents. You need to add elements outside the blocks in base.html if you want to see them on the final rendered page.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I haven't really understood the concept of templates and that's why I have wrongly interpreted. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Home.html -->

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
    Home
            {% endblock %}
                {% block body %}
                <h1>HomeHome</h1>
                {% endblock %}
```

base.html  -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>
        {% block head %}
        Base
        {% endblock %}
</title>
    </head>
    <body>

                {% block body %}
                <h1>BaseBase</h1>
                {% endblock %}
    
    </body></html>
```

If not working check your settings.py this code :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I know what I did wrong.